# Pandas groupby Month with annual summary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of items describing some orders placed like this

```
items=[('September 2021',1,40),('June 2022',1,77),....]
```

In order to get a dataframe grouped by how many orders did I receive and how much did I get paid I do the following

```
tabla2=tabla.sort_values(by=['Date']).groupby(['Date']).agg({'Subscriptions':'count','Total amount (€)':'sum'}).astype('float64').round(2)
```

What I want is to include a row with the yearly numbers after each month of that year, and a Totals at the bottom of it

For the totals I do the following

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series({'Date':"<b>Totals</b>",'Subscriptions':"<b>{}</b>".format(tabla['Subscriptions'].sum().astype('int')),
'Total amount (€)':"<b>{}</b>".format(tabla['Total amount (€)'].sum().round(2))})).T.set_index(['Date'])

tabla2=tabla2.append(df1)
```

The `<b>` is for making it bold later when representing it with plotly.

So I end up having something like this

```
Date            Subscriptions  Total amount (€)
September 2021             15              345
....                      ...              ...

<b>2021</b>               132             1256
June 2022                  17              452
...                       ...              ...
<b>2022</b>               144             3215
<b>Totals</b>            1234             4567
```

What is the most pythonic way of accomplish this from the `tabla2` dataframe?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a very bad way to represent your data, specially in a dataframe.

Comment: @QuangHoang why is that? How would you do it? Bear in mind that this table is a midstep towards printing it with plotly

Comment: Hi, so are you encountering an error/problem or are you seeking advice to improve your code?